# Facebook Social Widget shows no stream data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have a social widget of a FB page on a website. However there is no streaming data when I set the `data-stream="true"` attribute.

Is this a setting in the FB page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok apparently FB does not stream page data that is older than one or two months. My page was outdated. Streaming Data showed up after I posted something to the page timeline.

Cheers